# joomla list from api

Tags: html, api, list, joomla

how do I define selected in joomla list using the api? If I try to use the following snippet
won't work.

```
JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'jform[faculty]', array('class' => 'nourritures', 'option.attr' => 'data', 'selected'=>  $actual_record));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's "list.select" not "selected":

please see http://www.fasterjoomla.com/joomla-dev/joomla-select-options-with-style for a complete example.